# Ubuntu 16.10 Resize LVM issue

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, lvm

I have an Ubuntu image running inside VirtualBox and have followed the online instructions for increasing the VDI image successfully. VirtualBox correctly displays the disk size.

I have also used GParted to extend the existing LVM to extend my existing LVM into the new space, but my OS still doesn't recognize the additional space. I've been trying to use the suggestion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/917988/gparted-cannot-resize-extended-or-lvm-partition) for getting the OS to see the new usable space, but I'm running into errors.

Here are the commands I'm running per the suggestion:

```
lvextend –l +100%FREE [MOUNTPOINT]
```

and

```
sudo resize2fs [MOUNTPOINT]
```

But, when I run the last command I see the following error:

> ```
> resize2fs /dev/docker-vg/root resize2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
> Filesystem at /dev/docker-vg/root is mounted on/; on-line resizing
> required old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 3 resize2fs:
> Permission denied to resize filesystem
> ```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

So, I seemed to have assumed that you run the commands from within the OS. When I booted to the GParted disk I was able to run the resize commands successfully